# Cannot install passenger standalone 3.0.X on Mac OS X Mavericks, nginx compile fails

Tags: nginx, passenger, osx-mavericks

Trying to develop an existing Rails 3.0 application on a Mac with a clean install of Mavericks. Passenger Standalone was working fine under Mountain Lion. I upgraded to Mavericks, installed the command line tools, ruby, bundler, etc. When I get to this step:

```
passenger start
```

And passenger tries to compile nginx, it fails out with this error:

```
 adding module in /Users/ben/.passenger/standalone/3.0.21-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-macosx-10.9/support/ext/nginx
*** The Phusion Passenger support files are not yet compiled. Compiling them for you... ***
*** Running 'rake nginx RELEASE=yes' in /Users/ben/.passenger/standalone/3.0.21-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-macosx-10.9/support/ext/nginx... ***
(in /Users/ben/.passenger/standalone/3.0.21-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-macosx-10.9/support)
g++ -Iext  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -g -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -o ext/common/libboost_oxt/aggregate.o -c ext/common/libboost_oxt/aggregate.cpp
In file included from ext/common/libboost_oxt/aggregate.cpp:8:
In file included from ext/oxt/system_calls.cpp:26:
In file included from ext/boost/thread.hpp:24:
In file included from ext/boost/thread/future.hpp:14:
In file included from ext/boost/exception_ptr.hpp:9:
In file included from ext/boost/exception/detail/exception_ptr.hpp:19:
In file included from ext/boost/exception/info.hpp:15:
In file included from ext/boost/exception/to_string_stub.hpp:15:
In file included from ext/boost/exception/detail/object_hex_dump.hpp:14:
ext/boost/exception/detail/type_info.hpp:53:9: error: cannot define the implicit default assignment operator for 'boost::exception_detail::type_info_', because non-static reference member 'type_' can't use default assignment operator
        type_info_
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:1246:35: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::pair<boost::exception_detail::type_info_, boost::shared_ptr<boost::exception_detail::error_info_base> >::operator=' requested here
                __cache->__value_ = *__first;
                                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:1187:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__tree<std::__1::pair<boost::exception_detail::type_info_, boost::shared_ptr<boost::exception_detail::error_info_base> >, std::__1::__map_value_compare<boost::exception_detail::type_info_, boost::shared_ptr<boost::exception_detail::error_info_base>, std::__1::less<boost::exception_detail::type_info_>, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<boost::exception_detail::type_info_, boost::shared_ptr<boost::exception_detail::error_info_base> > > >::__assign_multi<std::__1::__tree_const_iterator<std::__1::pair<boost::exception_detail::type_info_, boost::shared_ptr<boost::exception_detail::error_info_base> >, const std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<boost::exception_detail::type_info_, boost::shared_ptr<boost::exception_detail::error_info_base> >, void *> *, long> >' requested here
        __assign_multi(__t.begin(), __t.end());
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/map:766:21: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__tree<std::__1::pair<boost::exception_detail::type_info_, boost::shared_ptr<boost::exception_detail::error_info_base> >, std::__1::__map_value_compare<boost::exception_detail::type_info_, boost::shared_ptr<boost::exception_detail::error_info_base>, std::__1::less<boost::exception_detail::type_info_>, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<boost::exception_detail::type_info_, boost::shared_ptr<boost::exception_detail::error_info_base> > > >::operator=' requested here
            __tree_ = __m.__tree_;
                    ^
ext/boost/exception/info.hpp:160:26: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::map<boost::exception_detail::type_info_, boost::shared_ptr<boost::exception_detail::error_info_base>, std::__1::less<boost::exception_detail::type_info_>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const boost::exception_detail::type_info_, boost::shared_ptr<boost::exception_detail::error_info_base> > > >::operator=' requested here
                c->info_ = info_;
                         ^
ext/boost/exception/detail/type_info.hpp:55:41: note: declared here
            detail::sp_typeinfo const & type_;
                                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/utility:255:15: note: implicit default copy assignment operator for 'boost::exception_detail::type_info_' first required here
        first = __p.first;
              ^
1 error generated.
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [g++ -Iext  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/inclu...]

Tasks: TOP => nginx => agents/nginx/PassengerHelperAgent => ext/common/libboost_oxt.a => ext/common/libboost_oxt/aggregate.o
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
*** ERROR: command failed: sh ./configure --prefix=/tmp --with-cc-opt='-Wno-error' --without-pcre --without-http_rewrite_module --without-http_fastcgi_module '--add-module=/Users/ben/.passenger/standalone/3.0.21-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-macosx-10.9/support/ext/nginx'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Phusion Passenger 3.0.21. That version does not work on Mavericks. Upgrade to 4.0.21 instead. By the way, the recommended way to install Passenger on OS X these days is via Homebrew. Follow the guide at https://www.phusionpassenger.com/download#open_source

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will there ever be a Mavericks compatible version of Passenger on the 3.0.X branch or are you only intending to support it on the 4.X branch? We're having some trouble getting our app running on 4.0.21 as passenger seems to think our app is Rails 1 or 2 instead of Rails 3. We have no config.ru file and somehow that is causing a problem with detection.

Comment: We only support 4.x now. Please submit a bug report regarding your problem.

Comment: Thanks again. Never mind about the Rails detection error. I added a config.ru file and app works just fine under 4.0.21. Kindest regards, ~Ben